# Not Implemented in Portable Class Library. Using Riverts with Xamarin in iOS app

Tags: ios, xamarin

I have a problem in Xamarin project. I use VS2015 and I try add App Link to my iOS app.

I found a tutorial [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/app-links/app-links-ios/). When I try to open my link in Safari everything works fine, but when debugger is in the OpenUrl function, I get this exception:

`System.NotImplementedException: Not Implemented in Portable Class Library.  Use a platform specific assembly instead.`

The code is:

```
var rurl = new Rivets.AppLinkUrl(url.ToString());
```

The URL has the address which I added in Safari. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rivets component that you are using cannot invoke the platform-specific code to work with the AppLink. Make sure you have also added the Rivets component or DLL to your iOS project, not just your PCL project.